# How to find the index of a given item in a list in a pandas column and extract the address from a column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a list

```
In [1]:list=['AM','PM','MT']
```

and i have a df like this

```
In [1]:d= {'Date': ['8/10/2021','8/10/2021','8/11/2021','8/11/2021','8/11/2021','8/11/2021','8/11/2021'],
    'Name': [ 'John','Jason','Derek','Foley','Jason','Derek J','Derek M'],
    'Notes':['John is at 234 gamer AMSTRONG AM','Jason did not come','He has 400 pens on 987 Gol power Beam PM, but he was sick','2897 Pace Terrance MT','Jason with 200gems on 2050 Bat Place,AM','Derek J at 390 Jackson Groove,PM,atleast he came','No Show'
]}
In [2]:df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['Date', 'Name','Notes'])

Out[1]:
  Date      Name    Notes
8/10/2021   John    John is at 234 gamer AMSTRONG AM
8/10/2021   Jason   Jason did not come
8/11/2021   Derek   He has 400 pens on 987 Gol power Beam PM, but he was sick
8/11/2021   Foley   2897 Pace Terrance MT
8/11/2021   Jason   Jason with 200gems on 2050 Bat Place,AM
8/11/2021   Derek J Derek J at 390 Jackson Groove,PM,atleast he came
8/11/2021   Derek M No Show
```

I want to extract the Address out of the Notes section. What I have done so far is as follows:

```
In [1]:Bool1 = df.iloc[:, 2].str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(list)))
In [2]:df['Yes?'] =Bool1
Out[1]:
Date        Name    Yes?    Notes
8/10/2021   John    TRUE    John is at 234 gamer AMSTRONG AM
8/10/2021   Jason   FALSE   Jason did not come
8/11/2021   Derek   TRUE    He has 400 pens on 987 Gol power Beam PM, but he was sick
8/11/2021   Folley  TRUE    2897 Pace Terrance MT
8/11/2021   Jason   TRUE    Jason with 200gems on 2050 Bat Place,AM
8/11/2021   Derek J TRUE    Derek J at 390 Jackson Groove,PM,atleast he came
8/11/2021   Derek M FALSE   No Show
```

What i would like is to find the index of the characters in the list when they show up ion the column of the df and then return the 20 characters to the left of it. I do not know how to find the index of the item in list in the column in the df.

Desired Output:

```
Out[1]:
Date       Name     Yes?        Address            Notes
8/10/2021   John    TRUE    234 gamer AMSTRONG AM  John is at 234 gamer AMSTRONG AM
8/10/2021   Jason   FALSE                          Jason did not come
8/11/2021   Derek   TRUE    987 Gol power Beam PM  He has 400 pens on 987 Gol power Beam PM, but he was sick
8/11/2021   Folley  TRUE    2897 Pace Terrance MT  2897 Pace Terrance MT
8/11/2021   Jason   TRUE    2050 Bat Place,AM      Jason with 200gems on 2050 Bat Place,AM
8/11/2021   Derek J TRUE    390 Jackson Groove,PM  Derek J at 390 Jackson Groove,PM,atleast he came
8/11/2021   Derek M FALSE                          No Show
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work?

```
import pandas as pd

#  create a simple data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5,5)), 
                  columns={'a','b','c','d','e'}, 
                  index={'1/1/2020', '2/1/2020', '3/1/2020', '4/1/2020','5/1/2020'})
# add some values to look for
df['g'] = [6,7,'find me!',9,10]

find_this = 'find me!'
idx = df[df.eq(find_this).any(1)].index
display(idx)
# returns "Index(['4/1/2020'], dtype='object')"
```